# Combine 2 images as a single planar image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, overlay, spectrogram

I have two separate gray scale images `im1` (Fig1) and `im2` (Fig2) each of size 50 by 50 that are displayed here by color coding them. When I combine them together using `cat()` command and then display the result of concatenated images, they get displayed side by side (Fig3). However, if I create a third image by replicating either the first of the second image and then  display the concatenation of the 3 images I get a single image (Fig4). I don't understand how the merging for the RGB (3 dimensions) could be possible whereas for the conversion to grayscale the merging did not happen. How can I get a single image using the two images `im1` and `im2` merged or overlayed whichever is legally possible and not side by side? Si how do I overlay `im1` and `im2` to get a single image and display it by color coding?

```
imgGray = cat(2,im1,im2);
imshow(imgGray)
imgGray = cat(2,im1,im2);  
imshow(imgGray)
imagesc(imgGray)
im3=im1;
imgColor = cat(3,im1,im2,im3);  
imagesc(imgColor)
```

[image: out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just add them to each other (**after normalizing them**) and have a single colormap represent it all

```
imagesc(I1+I2);
```

[image]

or if you want to set transparency according to the color and intensity you can add

```
alpha color
alpha scaled
```

Comment: Thank you for your answr, it seems straightforward. But how do I normalize the images as you mentioned in the first step?

Comment: first make sure that `I=double(I)`, so any operation you are doing will not mess with the information in the image. Normalize means wither setting the maximun to 1 via `I=I./max(I(:))` or deviding by the total intensity of the image `I=I./sum(I(:))`. see what makes sense to you...

Answer (score 1):

You can to do it "manually":

- Use `ind2rgb` for converting each Grayscale image to RGB with "color coding".
- Compute average of two RGB images for getting "fused image".

Here is a code sample:

```
% Use cameraman as first image, and resized moon for the second image (just for example).
I1 = imread('cameraman.tif'); % I1 is uint8 Grayscale
I2 = imresize(imread('moon.tif'), size(I1));  % I2 is uint8 Grayscale

% Convert images to RGB using parula color map (you may choose any color map).
J1 = ind2rgb(I1, parula(256)); % J1 is double RGB (three color planes in range [0, 1]).
J2 = ind2rgb(I2, parula(256)); % J2 is double RGB (three color planes in range [0, 1]).

% Fuse J1 and J2 "manually".
alpah = 0.5; % Using alpah=0.5, gives average of J1 and J2.
K = J1*alpah + J2*(1-alpah); %K is is double RGB.
K = im2uint8(K); % Convert K to uint8 (im2uint8 multiplies pixels by 255, and convert to uint8).

%Display result
figure;imshow(K);
```

Result:
[image]